# Application Loader rejects Binary due to Executable Name

Tags: ios, xcode, executable, loader

I am submitting an application through Application Loader, and it keeps rejecting my binary due to the same error:

"This bundle is invalid. The Executable name, as reported by CFBundleExecutable in the info.plist file, may not contain any of these characters: \ [] {} () . + *"

When I made the application, I named the project *Star Pong* . I left the Bundle Display Name, Bundle Name, and Executable File at their defaults (${PRODUCT_NAME}, ${PRODUCT_NAME}, and ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} respectively), although I have experimented, to no effect.

I would like to keep the name of the App the same, so how would I fix this problem? I have been on the point of hurting myself for the past two days wrestling with the problem, and I would REALLY appreciate the help.

Comment: this should answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17158773/2123093

Answer (score 0):

Reason is your Target name (Product name, executable name) contains special characters as (){}[]... Rename it by simply single click on TARGETS, remove special character, restart Xcode, re-archive and submit again. Remember!, don't need directly change Executable name in Info.plist file.