# Can't upload Archive to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store

My app name has a '+' in it. When I change my CFBundleExecutable (in my Info.plist file) To contain that +, I get an error that the CFBundleExecutable cannot contain the special character +. When I name my CFBundleExecutable to something different ('plus' instead of +), I get the error that the Bundle ID is not found. How should I deal with this!

Comment: I'm assuming that you changed + to plus only in the app, but you have to make sure that you have same bundle identifier in the developer apple profile too

Comment: my bundle ID has a 'plus' in it, and I have a proper app ID and provisioning profile named with 'plus.' not really sure what CFBundleExecutable is doing here @EugeneGordin

Comment: go through your info.plist files and make sure you have ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} as a value for all of the CFBundleExecutable

Comment: My CFBundleExecutable originally was "${EXECUTABLE_NAME}", which gave me the error `"This bundle is invalid. The executable name, as reported by CFBundleExecutable in the Info.plist file, may not contain any of these characters:\[ ] { } ( ) . + *"` which I assumed was being called because of the '+' @EugeneGordin

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275642/my-ios-app-has-a-in-its-name-bundle-is-invalid-due-to-this-need-help-resolvi) from googling my error. Sorry for the duplicate issue. I will look into this and get back

Comment: works. very happy. Also in case anyone runs across this issue you must add the `Bundle Display Name` row as mentioned in the link above.